# PHP exec call to python script with command line subprocess

Tags: php, python, apache, cgi

I am hoping someone with a bit more knowledge about PHP and web servers might be able to help me out. I have a HTML page that takes and uploaded zip file and then calls a PHP page as a form action. That PHP then calls two python scripts in my Apache cgi-bin. The first python script runs with no issue and simply unzips the uploaded file within a sub directory. The second python script includes a subprocess call to a command line tool to perform some action on the unzipped files. However, I am finding that using the exec() in PHP for the second python script with the subprocess does not work. If I run the python script from the command line it works fine. But, if I call it from the PHP exec function it does nothing.

The snippet of PHP:

```
    $tmp1 = exec("C:\\ms4w\\Python\\python C:\\ms4w\\Apache\\cgi-bin\\unzip_shp.py $without_extension");
    echo $tmp1;
    echo "<br>";        
    $tmp2 = exec("C:\\ms4w\\Python\\python C:\\ms4w\\Apache\\cgi-bin\\convert_to_geojson.py $without_extension", $output);
    echo $output
```

The snippet of python:

```
    command = "C:\\ms4w\\tools\\gdal-ogr\\ogr2ogr.exe -f \"GeoJSON\" "+sys.argv[1]+".geojson "+sys.argv[1]+".shp" #os.system(command)
    subprocess.check_call(command)
    print(command)
```

The print command in the python returns this to the PHP:

```
    C:\ms4w\tools\gdal-ogr\ogr2ogr.exe -f "GeoJSON" C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\uploads\parks_escambia.geojson C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\uploads\parks_escambia.shp
```

Also, I am running this all on a windows OS as a localhost development server. Using python version 2.7. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Derek

Comment: have you tried to `print(command)` before `check_call` ? can you [edit] your post to show that? and what does `check_call` return as an exception?

Comment: Hello. I just added the print statement and here is what I get back to the PHP and it all looks good there returning a valid command string that I can copy/paste and run from a DOS prompt

Comment: Gladly and thanks for moving my question forward.

Comment: is the current directory important? (also: in your snippet you're printing _before_ defining `command`, strange ...)

Comment: last question: how does the python script behave? does it crash? any error messages? (because `check_call` raises an exception if the command fails: i.e. returns a non-zero exit status)

Comment: good catch w/ the print statement. also, to your second question I added the $output as a parameter on check_call and then echo it after. It only prints "Array" which I am not sure how to interpret.

Comment: could you try `subprocess.check_call([r"C:\ms4w\tools\gdal-ogr\ogr2ogr.exe","-f","GeoJSON",sys.argv[1]+".geojson",sys.argv[1]+".shp"])`

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same result. Also, to answer your question earlier the current directory is important. I use os.chdir to change to the output the directory the files are that I am trying to create.

Comment: in that case add `cwd=` parameter to `check_call` instead of using `chdir`. avoid `chdir`

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately still the same result. Could it be a permission issue with what credentials PHP/localhost is running under?

Comment: have you tried to run an extract of your PHP script as the user where pasting in the terminal works?

Comment: Great idea. I like that you can run PHP at the terminal. However, it works as expected this way, but still not when loading from a webpage through localhost.

Comment: so it's neither a PHP problem or a python problem. It's a permissions problem when running from the webpage...